# Can search Elasticsearch 5.0 (Windows) using simple query, but prefixed with field name fails (search by example)

Tags: search, elasticsearch, mapping, field, wildcard

I am trying to get "search by example" functionality out of ElasticSearch.
I have a number of objects which have fields, e.g. name, description, objectID, etc.
I want to perform a search where, for example, "name=123" and "description=ABC"

Mapping:

```
{
"settings": {
    "number_of_replicas": 1,
    "number_of_shards": 3,      
    "refresh_interval": "5s",
    "index.mapping.total_fields.limit": "500"
},
"mappings": {   
    "CFS": {
        "_routing": {
            "required": true
        },
        "properties": {
            "objectId": {
                "store": true,
                "type": "keyword",
                "index": "not_analyzed" 
            },
            "name": {
                "type": "text",
                "analyzer": "standard"
            },
            "numberOfUpdates": {
                "type": "long"
            },
            "dateCreated": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis"
            },
            "lastModified": {
                "type": "date",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time||epoch_millis",
                "index": "not_analyzed" 
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

Trying a very simple search, without field name, gives correct result:

Request: GET http://localhost:9200/repository/CFS/_search?routing=CFS&q=CFS3

Returns:

```
{
  "took": 1,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 1,
    "max_score": 0.7831944,
    "hits": [
      {
        "_index": "repository",
        "_type": "CFS",
        "_id": "589a9a62-1e4d-4545-baf9-9cc7bf4d582a",
        "_score": 0.7831944,
        "_routing": "CFS",
        "_source": {
          "doc": {
            "name": "CFS3",
            "description": "CFS3Desc",
            "objectId": "589a9a62-1e4d-4545-baf9-9cc7bf4d582a",
            "lastModified": 1480524291530,
            "dateCreated": 1480524291530
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But trying to prefix with a field name fails (and this happens on all fields, e.g. objectId):

Request: GET http://localhost:9200/repository/CFS/_search?routing=CFS&q=name:CFS3

Returns:

```
{
  "took": 6,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 1,
    "successful": 1,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 0,
    "max_score": null,
    "hits": []
  }
}
```

Eventually I want to do something like:

```
{
  "bool" : {
    "must" : [
      {
        "wildcard" : {
          "name" : {
            "wildcard" : "*CFS3*",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      },
      {
        "wildcard" : {
          "description" : {
            "wildcard" : "*CFS3Desc*",
            "boost" : 1.0
          }
        }
      }
    ]    
  }
}
```

Maybe related?  When I try to use a "multi_match" to do this, I have to prefix my field name with a wildcard, e.g.

```
POST http://localhost:9200/repository/CFS/_search?routing=CFS
{
    "query": {
        "multi_match" : {
            "query" : "CFS3",
            "fields" : ["*name"]
        }
    }
}
```

If I don't prefix it, it doesn't find anything.  I've spent 2 days searching StackOverflow and the ElasticSearch documentation.  But these issues don't seem to be mentioned.
There's lots about wildcards for search terms, and even mention of wildcards AFTER the field name, but nothing about BEFORE the field name.
What piece of information am I missing from the field name, that I need to deal with by specifying a wildcard?

I think the types of my fields in the mapping are correct.  I'm specifying an analyzer.

Comment: What if you have your url as such, where having the name's value within quotes: `http://localhost:9200/repository/CFS/_search?routing=CFS&q=name:"CFS3"`

Comment: It may be, because wildcard query is not analyzed, and your "name" index is analyzed as standard (so lowercased) and then *CFS3* != cfs3 ...

Comment: Thank you both for your comments!
Putting quotes around "CFS3" didn't help.  I also tried using HTML codes for ":" (%3A).  I also tried the HTML code for "=" (%3D) but it just ignores the field name.
Tried lower case "cfs3", but again it didn't make a difference.  Also tried in tandem with Kulasangar's suggestion and wrapped it with double-quotes.
I'm sure there's something fundamental that's going wrong or that I haven't set up, but there's no clue as to what it is.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer to this :(
I had been keen to utilise "upserts", to avoid having to check if the object already existed, and to therefore keep performance high.

As you see at this link https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/partial-updates.html and this one https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-update.html when calling the Update REST call, you specify your payload as:

```
{
   "doc" : {
      "tags" : [ "testing" ],
      "views": 0
   }
}
```

When implementing the equivalent using the Java client, I didn't follow the examples exactly.  Instead of what was suggested:

```
UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest();
updateRequest.index("index");
updateRequest.type("type");
updateRequest.id("1");
updateRequest.doc(jsonBuilder()
        .startObject()
            .field("gender", "male")
        .endObject());
client.update(updateRequest).get();
```

I had implemented:

```
    JsonObject state = extrapolateStateFromEvent( event );
    JsonObject doc = new JsonObject();
    doc.add( "doc", state );

    UpdateRequest updateRequest = new UpdateRequest( indexName, event.getEntity().getType(), event.getEntity().getObjectId() );
    updateRequest.routing( event.getEntity().getType() );
    updateRequest.doc( doc.toString() );
    updateRequest.upsert( doc.toString() );
    UpdateResponse response = client.update( updateRequest ).get();
```

I wrapped my payload/"state" with a "doc" object, thinking it was needed.

But this had a large impact on how I interacted with my data, and at no point was I warned about it.
I guess I had accidentally created a nested object.  Although I wonder why it affects the search APIs so much?

How this could be improved?  Maybe the mapping could default to disallow nested objects?  Or there could be some kind of validation that a programmer could perform?